# Android - What is a secondary progress in ProgressBar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Anyone know about the detail? Any website or suggestion?

Comment: See the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385007/how-to-show-the-secondaryprogress-in-a-android-progressdialog for some example code and a screenshot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [the source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html):

> There is also a secondary progress
>   displayable on a progress bar which is
>   useful for displaying intermediate
>   progress, such as the buffer level
>   during a streaming playback progress
>   bar.

One can find a [fully worked example](https://android--examples.blogspot.co.il/2015/12/android-how-to-show-secondary.html) of displaying such a bar, including screenshots of the appearance of such a bar in a particular style (circular bar which fills from the bottom):

[image: Secondary Progress Bar]

In the image above, the secondary bar is the green area, when it reaches the top, some *subtask* is complete.

Comment: I saw that earlier. Any example? (With Picture)

Comment: These 2 links demonstrate this:
https://android--examples.blogspot.co.il/2015/12/android-how-to-show-secondary.html, and:
https://dzone.com/articles/android-example-progress-bar

Comment: Thanks @AlaaM. - I added one of the links to the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: A common example if your daily life is video streaming. The primary progress is the current playing time of the video, while the secondary progress is the downloaded part of the video.

Answer (score 2):

Secondary progress vs Progress can be thought of like the downloaded part of a video you're watching vs the complete length of the progress bar